# Criando array de dados vindo de uma tabela em php

Tags: php

Como salvar dados de uma tabela de modo que cada linha siga a data da coluna. Exemplo: Linha1 col1 = descricao1 e linha1 col2= valor1 e col2linha0= data1 salvando > descricao1 + valor1 + data1
Como criar uma array?

```html
//todos os dados recebidos dos inputs
//recebendo datas de cada coluna
    $dats1 = $_POST['dats1'];
    $dats2 = $_POST['dats2'];
    $dats3 = $_POST['dats3'];
    $dats4 = $_POST['dats4'];
    $dats5 = $_POST['dats5'];
    $dats6 = $_POST['dats6'];
    $dats7 = $_POST['dats7'];
    $dats8 = $_POST['dats8'];

    //Todo esquema para linha 1
    $a1 = $_POST['a1'];
    $a2 = $_POST['a2'];
    $a3 = $_POST['a3'];
    $a4 = $_POST['a4'];
    $a5 = $_POST['a5'];
    $a6 = $_POST['a6'];
    $a7 = $_POST['a7'];
    $a8 = $_POST['a8'];
    $desc1 = $_POST['desc1'];

        //Todo esquema para linha 2
    $b1 = $_POST['b1'];
    $b2 = $_POST['b2'];
    $b3 = $_POST['b3'];
    $b4 = $_POST['b4'];
    $b5 = $_POST['b5'];
    $b6 = $_POST['b6'];
    $b7 = $_POST['b7'];
    $b8 = $_POST['b8'];
    $desc2 = $_POST['desc2'];
        //Todo esquema para linha 3
    $c1 = $_POST['c1'];
    $c2 = $_POST['c2'];
    $c3 = $_POST['c3'];
    $c4 = $_POST['c4'];
    $c5 = $_POST['c5'];
    $c6 = $_POST['c6'];
    $c7 = $_POST['c7'];
    $c8 = $_POST['c8'];
    $desc3 = $_POST['desc3'];
        //Todo esquema para linha 4
    $d1 = $_POST['d1'];
    $d2 = $_POST['d2'];
    $d3 = $_POST['d3'];
    $d4 = $_POST['d4'];
    $d5 = $_POST['d5'];
    $d6 = $_POST['d6'];
    $d7 = $_POST['d7'];
    $d8 = $_POST['d8'];
    $desc4 = $_POST['desc4'];
        //Todo esquema para linha 5
    $e1 = $_POST['e1'];
    $e2 = $_POST['e2'];
    $e3 = $_POST['e3'];
    $e4 = $_POST['e4'];
    $e5 = $_POST['e5'];
    $e6 = $_POST['e6'];
    $e7 = $_POST['e7'];
    $e8 = $_POST['e8'];
    $desc5 = $_POST['desc5'];
        //Todo esquema para linha 6
    $f1 = $_POST['f1'];
    $f2 = $_POST['f2'];
    $f3 = $_POST['f3'];
    $f4 = $_POST['f4'];
    $f5 = $_POST['f5'];
    $f6 = $_POST['f6'];
    $f7 = $_POST['f7'];
    $f8 = $_POST['f8'];
    $desc6 = $_POST['desc6'];
        //Todo esquema para linha 7
    $g1 = $_POST['g1'];
    $g2 = $_POST['g2'];
    $g3 = $_POST['g3'];
    $g4 = $_POST['g4'];
    $g5 = $_POST['g5'];
    $g6 = $_POST['g6'];
    $g7 = $_POST['g7'];
    $g8 = $_POST['g8'];
    $desc7 = $_POST['desc7'];
        //Todo esquema para linha 8
    $h1 = $_POST['h1'];
    $h2 = $_POST['h2'];
    $h3 = $_POST['h3'];
    $h4 = $_POST['h4'];
    $h5 = $_POST['h5'];
    $h6 = $_POST['h6'];
    $h7 = $_POST['h7'];
    $h8 = $_POST['h8'];
    $desc8 = $_POST['desc8'];

    //Todo esquema para linha 9
    $i1 = $_POST['i1'];
    $i2 = $_POST['i2'];
    $i3 = $_POST['i3'];
    $i4 = $_POST['i4'];
    $i5 = $_POST['i5'];
    $i6 = $_POST['i6'];
    $i7 = $_POST['i7'];
    $i8 = $_POST['i8'];
    $desc9 = $_POST['desc9'];

    //Todo esquema para linha 10
    $j1 = $_POST['j1'];
    $j2 = $_POST['j2'];
    $j3 = $_POST['j3'];
    $j4 = $_POST['j4'];
    $j5 = $_POST['j5'];
    $j6 = $_POST['j6'];
    $j7 = $_POST['j7'];
    $j8 = $_POST['j8'];
    $desc10 = $_POST['desc10'];

    //Todo esquema para linha 11
    $k1 = $_POST['k1'];
    $k2 = $_POST['k2'];
    $k3 = $_POST['k3'];
    $k4 = $_POST['k4'];
    $k5 = $_POST['k5'];
    $k6 = $_POST['k6'];
    $k7 = $_POST['k7'];
    $k8 = $_POST['k8'];
    $desc11 = $_POST['desc11'];

    //Todo esquema para linha 12
    $l1 = $_POST['l1'];
    $l2 = $_POST['l2'];
    $l3 = $_POST['l3'];
    $l4 = $_POST['l4'];
    $l5 = $_POST['l5'];
    $l6 = $_POST['l6'];
    $l7 = $_POST['l7'];
    $l8 = $_POST['l8'];
    $desc12 = $_POST['desc12'];
```

Alguam ideia para eu melhorar esse codigo?

Comment: Pela sua pergunta, não dá pra entender o que você está querendo. Por favor, edite a pergunta, sendo mais específico. Do contrário, a mesma será fechada.

Comment: Acho que agora sera melhor o entendimento @Wallace Maxters acabei de editar.

Comment: @gezer poste o seu formulário de onde vem todos esses dados.

Comment: como não coube todo o codigo eu postei no jsfiddle

Comment: Tens de esclarecer melhor, afinal qual é o problema?

Comment: @Jorge B. o problema foi resolvido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude isso:

```
//todos os dados recebidos dos inputs
//recebendo datas de cada coluna
$dats1 = $_POST['dats1'];
$dats2 = $_POST['dats2'];
$dats3 = $_POST['dats3'];
$dats4 = $_POST['dats4'];
$dats5 = $_POST['dats5'];
$dats6 = $_POST['dats6'];
$dats7 = $_POST['dats7'];
$dats8 = $_POST['dats8'];

//Todo esquema para linha 1
$a1 = $_POST['a1'];
$a2 = $_POST['a2'];
$a3 = $_POST['a3'];
$a4 = $_POST['a4'];
$a5 = $_POST['a5'];
$a6 = $_POST['a6'];
$a7 = $_POST['a7'];
$a8 = $_POST['a8'];
$desc1 = $_POST['desc1'];

//Todo esquema para linha 2
$b1 = $_POST['b1'];
$b2 = $_POST['b2'];
$b3 = $_POST['b3'];
$b4 = $_POST['b4'];
$b5 = $_POST['b5'];
$b6 = $_POST['b6'];
$b7 = $_POST['b7'];
$b8 = $_POST['b8'];
$desc2 = $_POST['desc2'];

//Todo esquema para linha 3
$c1 = $_POST['c1'];
$c2 = $_POST['c2'];
$c3 = $_POST['c3'];
$c4 = $_POST['c4'];
$c5 = $_POST['c5'];
$c6 = $_POST['c6'];
$c7 = $_POST['c7'];
$c8 = $_POST['c8'];
$desc3 = $_POST['desc3'];

//Todo esquema para linha 4
$d1 = $_POST['d1'];
$d2 = $_POST['d2'];
$d3 = $_POST['d3'];
$d4 = $_POST['d4'];
$d5 = $_POST['d5'];
$d6 = $_POST['d6'];
$d7 = $_POST['d7'];
$d8 = $_POST['d8'];
$desc4 = $_POST['desc4'];

//Todo esquema para linha 5
$e1 = $_POST['e1'];
$e2 = $_POST['e2'];
$e3 = $_POST['e3'];
$e4 = $_POST['e4'];
$e5 = $_POST['e5'];
$e6 = $_POST['e6'];
$e7 = $_POST['e7'];
$e8 = $_POST['e8'];
$desc5 = $_POST['desc5'];

//Todo esquema para linha 6
$f1 = $_POST['f1'];
$f2 = $_POST['f2'];
$f3 = $_POST['f3'];
$f4 = $_POST['f4'];
$f5 = $_POST['f5'];
$f6 = $_POST['f6'];
$f7 = $_POST['f7'];
$f8 = $_POST['f8'];    
$desc6 = $_POST['desc6'];

//Todo esquema para linha 7
$g1 = $_POST['g1'];
$g2 = $_POST['g2'];
$g3 = $_POST['g3'];
$g4 = $_POST['g4'];
$g5 = $_POST['g5'];
$g6 = $_POST['g6'];
$g7 = $_POST['g7'];
$g8 = $_POST['g8'];
$desc7 = $_POST['desc7'];

//Todo esquema para linha 8
$h1 = $_POST['h1'];
$h2 = $_POST['h2'];
$h3 = $_POST['h3'];
$h4 = $_POST['h4'];
$h5 = $_POST['h5'];
$h6 = $_POST['h6'];
$h7 = $_POST['h7'];
$h8 = $_POST['h8'];
$desc8 = $_POST['desc8'];

//Todo esquema para linha 9
$i1 = $_POST['i1'];
$i2 = $_POST['i2'];
$i3 = $_POST['i3'];
$i4 = $_POST['i4'];
$i5 = $_POST['i5'];
$i6 = $_POST['i6'];
$i7 = $_POST['i7'];
$i8 = $_POST['i8'];
$desc9 = $_POST['desc9'];

//Todo esquema para linha 10
$j1 = $_POST['j1'];
$j2 = $_POST['j2'];
$j3 = $_POST['j3'];
$j4 = $_POST['j4'];
$j5 = $_POST['j5'];
$j6 = $_POST['j6'];
$j7 = $_POST['j7'];
$j8 = $_POST['j8'];
$desc10 = $_POST['desc10'];

//Todo esquema para linha 11
$k1 = $_POST['k1'];
$k2 = $_POST['k2'];
$k3 = $_POST['k3'];
$k4 = $_POST['k4'];
$k5 = $_POST['k5'];
$k6 = $_POST['k6'];
$k7 = $_POST['k7'];
$k8 = $_POST['k8'];
$desc11 = $_POST['desc11'];

//Todo esquema para linha 12
$l1 = $_POST['l1'];
$l2 = $_POST['l2'];
$l3 = $_POST['l3'];
$l4 = $_POST['l4'];
$l5 = $_POST['l5'];
$l6 = $_POST['l6'];
$l7 = $_POST['l7'];
$l8 = $_POST['l8'];
$desc12 = $_POST['desc12'];
```

Para:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 8; $i++) {


    $dats[$i] = $_POST['dats'.$i];
    $a[$i] = $_POST['a'.$i];
    $b[$i] = $_POST['b'.$i];
    $c[$i] = $_POST['c'.$i];
    $d[$i] = $_POST['d'.$i];
    $e[$i] = $_POST['e'.$i];
    $f[$i] = $_POST['f'.$i];
    $g[$i] = $_POST['g'.$i];
    $h[$i] = $_POST['h'.$i];
    $i[$i] = $_POST['i'.$i];
    $j[$i] = $_POST['j'.$i];
    $k[$i] = $_POST['k'.$i];
    $l[$i] = $_POST['l'.$i];  
}

$desc1 = $_POST['desc1'];
$desc2 = $_POST['desc2'];
$desc3 = $_POST['desc3'];
$desc4 = $_POST['desc4'];
$desc5 = $_POST['desc5'];
$desc6 = $_POST['desc6'];
$desc7 = $_POST['desc7'];
$desc8 = $_POST['desc8'];
$desc9 = $_POST['desc9'];
$desc10 = $_POST['desc10'];
$desc11 = $_POST['desc11'];
$desc12 = $_POST['desc12'];
```

Desta forma já irá reduzir as linhas. E não esqueça que desta forma está com array então na hora de inserir as variáveis para o array por exemplo:

```
$a1 para $a[1];
```

Comment: hum entendo vai ajudar bastante obrigado pela dica

Comment: Que bom amigo, Fico feliz em saber que irá ajudar. Valeu cara abraço e boa sorte em seu projeto aí.

Comment: e tambem for ($x = 1; $x< 8; $x++) {  $desc[$x] = $_POST['desc'.$x]; }    valew meu brhoter pela dica de mais de 1000 linhas se reduziram agora rs.

Comment: Porque desse erro Cannot use a scalar value as an array @Viniam